# Why Stream.iterate returns null as the first element

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to initialize random 5 elements(Object) and I'm trying to use **Stream.iterate** function but something it's wrong first element(object) always is **null**.

```
Stream.iterate(new Student(), s -> {
        s.setId(new Random().nextInt(5));
        s.setUsername(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        s.setPassword(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return s;
}).limit(5)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Student{id=null, username=null, password=null}
Student{id=0, username=7d7403e0-89f0-4033-a874-31e0aae1d7c6, password=590baa12-a9f7-4fef-8a47-4bcb7f2174d1}
Student{id=3, username=d75bff67-a1f7-4969-9418-93f3e0eb1cd7, password=9e48d614-a15e-4f2a-9e87-63ed3a81f410}
Student{id=3, username=47943516-e8bd-4ffe-bc47-4e251104994a, password=f2d4d02d-2e37-4346-a51d-b83f40044c68}
Student{id=2, username=1a1e5f9e-7fac-439f-b5f2-2931884e0772, password=9df36248-5e1e-4b28-b1c0-020123dd26b8}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

As a complement to the given answer: using `iterate` the way you do, you actually create only one instance of `Student` that you keep mutating.

It is fine as long you consume each element of the stream with the `forEach` method. If you collected your stream in a `List`, you would get a list of 5 times the same element after having applied the last mutation.

If you want to create several instances, use `generate`:

```
Stream.generate(() -> new Student(new Random().nextInt(5), 
                                  UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                                  UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
      .limit(5)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: The question’s code will also break for any case where more than one element exists at a time, e.g. with `reduce` which includes operation like `min` and `max`, and for hidden intermediate storage like with `sorted()`, as well as for parallel streams.

Answer (score 5):

The first element in what `Stream.iterate()` returns is the seed element, i.e. the new Student() you provided. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm found solutions for my problem which is based on previous answers

```
Stream.generate(Student::new)
        .map(s -> {
            s.setId(new Random().nextInt(5));
            s.setUsername(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            s.setPassword(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            return s;
        }).limit(5)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Thanks All.

Comment: You can do everything in `generate` without the `map` step which actually in your case doesn't map.